# flutter firebase dynamic links - wrong link is captured in app

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm trying to capture the query paramters of a dynamic link.
In firebase console, the dynamic link is set as

`myApp.page.link/myPage?par1=1,par2=2`

The link that I build programmatically is:

`http://myapp.page.link/myPage?st= Hi there &amv=0&apn=com.myapp&ibi=com.myapp&imv=0&link=https://myapp.page.link/myPage?par1=123&par=456`

When I capture the link in the app, using FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink, I get

`myApp.page.link/myPage?par1=1,par2=2`

instead on the expected parameters par1=123, par2=456.

Flutter doctor has no errors

What can it be?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it might have been the fact that although I was using a device as an "emulator" in a debug mode.
Once using the "real" app from google store, the problem was gone :-)